# NEON code faster than standard C code on armeabi-v7a but slower on arm64-v8a

Tags: c, performance, optimization, simd, neon

I was trying out [hello neon](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-neon) sample provided by `android/ndk-samples` and tested the fir filter demo on two devices one with `armeabi-v7a` support and other with `arm64-v8a` ABI.

By default the [JNI code](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/main/hello-neon/app/src/main/cpp/helloneon.c) fails for `arm64-v8a` but that can be addressed with some tweaks. Now when I finally run the comparison code on the two devices (with diff specs) I get following results

#### `armeabi-v7a` device - quad core, 32bit

```
C Version:      182.47 ms
Neon Version:   69.782 ms (2.62x faster)
```

#### `arm64-v8a` device - octa core, 64bit

```
C Version:      10.189 ms
Neon Version:   19.4836 ms (0.52295x faster)
```

### Question

Why does this neon version slow down for the `arm64-v8a`?

(I am fairly new to NEON and SIMD)

Link to intrinsic code - [cpp/helloneon-intrinsics.c](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/main/hello-neon/app/src/main/cpp/helloneon-intrinsics.c)

Comment: How are you compiling the code, i.e. what compiler switches are you passing in each case ?

Comment: `v7a` with `-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a` and `v8a` with  `-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a`

Comment: Without compiler optimization like `-O2` or `-O3`?

Comment: numbers of cores does not matter. Yuor code is executed on one :). Enable optimizations

Comment: It's an extremely bad example. The four `sum += vgetq_lane_s32(sum_vec, 0);` lines will cause full pipeline halts. Don't waste your time with the neon examples included in AOSP. They are baaaaad.

Comment: As @JérômeRichard says, unless you enable compiler optimisations (e.g. -O3) then your results are meaningless.

Comment: I see I'll try this, thanks! Meanwhile, how come it gives speedup for `armeabi-v7a`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE - Could you share example or better reference on what could be a faster implementation or where I could refer to for better examples? This hello neon example seems to be inspired from arm's documentation ([example](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Code-Examples-with-Optimization/FIR-filter/Using-NEON-intrinsics))

Comment: @PaulR - I still see same performance ratio after adding `-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-Ofast` flags (both goth a small speedup but same ratio). Same with `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O2` & `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O3`

Comment: This is apparently a C code and and not a C++ one, so `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` will not make any difference. Try to add the same macro for the C language. You can check the code is optimized by adding a stupid useless long loop in your code like `for(size_t i=0 ; i<1000*1000*1000 ; ++i);` and see if it takes some time. Another solution is to look the command lines executed by CMake. Alternatively, you can check the output assembly code changed.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does this neon version slow down for the arm64-v8a?

Because the code you have linked was written in 2016 for ARMv7.

In ARMv7, 8-byte NEON registers are individually addressable.

ARM64 SIMD is 16-bytes all the way down, 8-byte vectors have non-trivial performance penalty.

Try this version:

```
void fir_filter_neon_arm64( short *output, const short* input, const short* kernel, size_t width, size_t kernelSize )
{
    const ptrdiff_t offset = -(ptrdiff_t)kernelSize / 2;
    const size_t kernelSizeAligned = ( kernelSize / 8 ) * 8;
    const bool extraVector = ( kernelSize % 8 ) >= 4;

    for( size_t outer = 0; outer < width; outer++ )
    {
        const short* const inputPtr = input + outer + offset;
        // Handle stuff 16 bytes at a time.
        // Using 2 independent accumulators to improve data dependency situation on these accumulators.
        int32x4_t acc1 = vdupq_n_s32( 0 );
        int32x4_t acc2 = vdupq_n_s32( 0 );

        size_t ii = 0;
        for( ; ii < kernelSizeAligned; ii += 8 )
        {
            int16x8_t kernel_vec = vld1q_s16( kernel + ii );
            int16x8_t input_vec = vld1q_s16( inputPtr + ii );
            acc1 = vmlal_s16( acc1, vget_low_s16( kernel_vec ), vget_low_s16( input_vec ) );
            acc2 = vmlal_high_s16( acc2, kernel_vec, input_vec );
        }
        if( extraVector )
        {
            // The remainder was longer than 4, use SIMD for the first 4 of the remaining elements
            int16x4_t kernel_vec = vld1_s16( kernel + ii );
            int16x4_t input_vec = vld1_s16( inputPtr + ii );
            acc1 = vmlal_s16( acc1, kernel_vec, input_vec );
            ii += 4;
        }

        // Add these two accumulators together
        acc1 = vaddq_s32( acc1, acc2 );
        // Horizontal sum into the scalar, ARM64 has an instruction for that
        const int sumVector = vaddvq_s32( acc1 );

        // Handle the final 0-3 elements
        int sumRemainder = 0;
        for( ; ii < kernelSize; ii++ )
            sumRemainder += (int)( kernel[ ii ] ) * (int)( inputPtr[ ii ] );

        // Store the final result
        const int sum = sumVector + sumRemainder;
        output[ outer ] = (short)( ( sum + 0x8000 ) >> 16 );
    }
}
```

If building with GCC, make sure to `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` otherwise the compiler automatically vectorizes that one last loop with the remainder, inflates code for no good reason. With that command-line switch, the code [looks reasonable](https://godbolt.org/z/1v6e55r93).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and providing a code sample. I could verify that the neon code you shared is indeed faster than the `v7a` sample when running on a 64 bit Android device. Also, with `-fno-tree-vectorize` the neon code runs faster than the C code - but its actually slowing down the C code. With this flag I get: `31.7ms & 12.3 ms` for C & neon code while with just `-O3` flag I get `6.2 ms & 9.58 ms` for C & neon code respectively.

Comment: @Minhaz You probably have some other C code running there which benefits a lot from the automatic vectorizer.
Unfortunately, gcc doesn’t have an equivalent of msvc’s `#pragma loop( no_vector )`, but you can move the above function to a separate `*.c` file, and apply the `-fno-tree-vectorize` to that file only.